# JS: addClass on click and removeClass on window click (or outside of div)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a `classList` to an element "onclick", then remove that `classList` after any click.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".section-projects-img");

images.forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener("click", () => {
        img.classList.toggle("changed");
    }); 
});
```

this adds/removes when I click on the image, but I want it removed no matter where I click so that more than one img can't have same `classList`. I've tried adding `classList` to the element then removing by using `classList.contains()`. This seems super simple and quite embarrassing I can't figure it out. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because events bubble up from the event target right up to the top level element, we can do something like this:

```js
// just one event listener
document.body.addEventListener('click', clickEventDispatch, false);

function clickEventDispatch (e) {

  var _evt = (e.target || this);

  console.log(_evt.nodeName, _evt.className);

  /* 
    in practice you might want to change the criteria,
    and indeed possibly use if/else if instead of switch,
    but this will do for the purposes of demonstration:
  */
  switch (_evt.nodeName) {
    // it's an image
    case "IMG":
      /*
      EDIT:
      Didn't realise you wanted to toggle if active image clicked
      This oughta do it
      */
      if (_evt.classList.contains('changed')) {
        _evt.classList.remove('changed') 
      } 
      else { 
        resetChangedImages();
        _evt.classList.add('changed')
      };
      break;
 
    // it's not an image
    default:
      resetChangedImages();
  }
  
}

function resetChangedImages () {
  /* 
    [].slice.call here just converts the NodeList we get 
    from querySelectorAll into an Array we can iterate over 
    with forEach, rather than having to use for loop
  */
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function (img) { 
    img.classList.remove('changed');
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 32px 16px 200px;
  background: #d1d1d1;
}
.section-projects-img {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.changed {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="section-projects-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/2BLYrIxs.jpg" />
  <img class="section-projects-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/PIdF6ANs.jpg" />
  <img class="section-projects-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/uVm9rTfs.jpg" />
  <img class="section-projects-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6x0UzSVs.jpg" />
  <img class="section-projects-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/mvqzSFMs.jpg" />
</div>
```

This means we're not adding an event listener for every image, just one on the body, and then if you need event listeners for other elements like buttons etc. you can just include them in your event dispatcher function.

Comment: So this helps with making sure just one img holds a classList of "changed", but how can I also add a toggle to this to where clicking the "changed" img also removes the classList. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it does what you want now. And no problem!

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks, man. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is only to prevent more than one image from having the `changed` class, simply loop through all images and remove the class in the `click` event listener.

Do remember to first check whether the image being looped through is the image clicked however, otherwise the class will never be removed (the class is removed but toggled back again):

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".section-projects-img");

images.forEach(img => {
  img.addEventListener("click", () => {
    images.forEach(e => e != img ? e.classList.remove("changed") : '');
    img.classList.toggle("changed");
  });
});
```

```css
.changed {
  filter: brightness(2);
}
```

```html
<img class="section-projects-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
<img class="section-projects-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
<img class="section-projects-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
```